# How to understand this conversation?

Tags: meaning

Here’s a conversation in the book “Practical Conversation in English for Intermediate Student”:
[image: First page][image: Second page]

It’s a copied book. There are mistakes on almost every page. Here’s my comprehension of the conversation:

- **Shall we go to this movie?** This movie means the movies(cinema) or a film?
- Why doesn’t George specify which film when he buys tickets?
- I think **immediate seating** is wrong. It should be *immediately take a seat*.
- **Is that the feature picture?** does THAT refer to the picture beginning in 20mn or the one playing now?
- **Let’s wait for the next show, George.** I think WAIT means wait in the cinema rather than going outside.
- **We won’t have to see the end of the picture first, then.** Why? And what film is *the picture*?
- Are popcorn and coke sold in there? I think they’re sold outside.

Comment: This is a very quaint book, especially, "Move along, folks". It was from a time when movie theaters were not multiplexes but single-screen.  And **dose** should be **does**.

Comment: I saw a couple of typos, yes, it sounds like the 1940's or 1950's. Does it actually say: for Intermediate Student?? Maybe it's a book from the KGB for their students, because that lack of an a is a red flag. How about you give us a link for it? That might explain the typos...

Comment: Please don't include images of text unless it's necessary to understand the context (like in a meme). Write the text in your post.

Answer (score 3):

I will make a distinction between *cinema* and *theatre* with regards to movies. The c inema is the whole building including the ticket booth,kiosk, etc. The theatre is the actual part of the cinema where you sit down and watch a film.

As @Tᴚoɯɐuo said, this story comes from a time when cinemas only had a single theatre, which only showed a single movie, so you did not have a list of movies that you could select from.

- Shall we go to this movie? This movie means the only movie that is being shown at the cinema.
- Why doesn’t George specify which film when he buys tickets? He did not have to. There was only one movie to see.
- I think immediate seating is wrong. Immediate seating means that you don't have to wait until the current movie finishes before entering the theatre. As a consequence you would see the last part of the current movie and then the movie would start again so that you could see the rest.
- Is that the feature picture? George is asking if it is the feature film that starts in 20 minutes. the usher tells him that two short films will be shown before the main feature starts. So, in 20 minutes time the first short film will start.
- Let’s wait for the next show, George. Anne suggests that they do not enter the theatre immediately, but wait until the current session is finished.
- We won’t have to see the end of the picture first, then. George agrees with Anne as this will mean that they will not have to watch the end of the current film before the next session starts. He suggests that go and get popcorn.
- Are popcorn and coke sold in there? Most cinemas have a kiosk near the ticket booth where you can purchase confectionery, popcorn and drinks before going into the theatre to watch the movie. However, some cinemas also have people who sell a small selection of these items within the theatre before the movie starts.  In this case, George is suggesting that they go to the kiosk.

Comment: This is a "period piece" which is clearly also a bit of Americana.

Comment: So it means there’s only one movie being played again and again, right?

Comment: Probably, yes, but not necessarily.  It was not unusual, back when this story takes place, for a cinema to show a film in the afternoon, that children could go to, and a different film in the evening for adults to go to. Depending on the time they opened, a cinema could fit in 6 or 7 sessions a day, allowing time fo quickly clean the cinema between sessions.